# Trouble getting the first 25 values that are not present in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Hey so I know that I could do

```
(array - array 2).first(25)
```

and get the first 25 values that are not present when comparing the two arrays, however my situation is a bit more difficult.

I have a twitter app where I store search queries. I run a background job every hour, and sometimes if the query is not as popular I might save the same query. However I specifically want to get the first 25. Sometimes I for example only end up getting 18, because I have a model validation that the tweet id must be unique to the user.

What I know is that the twitter search gives you the 100 recent tweets of a result. So what I would like to do in order to combat this situation is map the current tweet ids I have, and use that on the query, and then get the first 25 of those results.

The problem is I need to store more info than just the tweet id, if not it would have been as easy as the code shown. So here is what I have currently:

```
def save_keyword
    active_campaigns = campaigns.where(live: true)
    total_keywords = active_campaigns.count.to_i
    tweet_amount = (get_tweets_per_hour / total_keywords).to_f.floor rescue 0
    begin
      active_campaigns.each do |campaign|
        self.twitter.search(campaign.keyword, result_type: 'recent').take(tweet_amount).map do |tweet|
          favorites.create do |favorite|
            favorite.tweet_id     = tweet.id
            favorite.owner_id     = tweet.user.id
            favorite.campaign_id  = campaign.id
          end
        end
      end
    rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
      sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in + 1
      retry
    rescue Twitter::Error::Unauthorized => error
      logger.error 'Unauthorized access'
    rescue => error
      logger.error 'save_keyword error'
    end
end
```

as I said I store info like the owner_id, tweet_id and the campaign id. So I need to create a code that gives me, or keeps on saving the keyword until it's 25.

Comment: What gem are you using to provide `self.twitter.search`?

Comment: Can´t you use `favorites.find_or_create_by` to solve the issue with the unique tweet id?

Comment: that's not really the problem. The problem I'm having is I'm currently saving the first 25 queries. What I'd like to do is if I have previously saved one of those before is to get the first 25 queries where I have not saved them prior. Find or create would just work like a validation, which I already have

Answer (score 0):

You do it by querying `Favorite` and using the tweet id to filter the results:

```
old_tweets = Favorite.where( campaign_id: campaign.id ).pluck(:tweet_id)
tweets = self.twitter.search(campaign.keyword, result_type: 'recent')
new_tweets = tweets.reject { |t| old_tweets.include?(t.id) }.take(tweet_amount)
```

Comment: Not the most elegant code ever - sorry. Got a train to catch.

Comment: then just run new_tweets.map do |tweet| and proceed as normal?

Comment: Exactly, the difference here is that you are filtering the set before you limit it. I made small typo and left the ? off `old_tweets.includes?` which is fixed in an edit.